# Expand an NSCell when multiples lines

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nscell

I'd like to have the same behaviour that Console.app in 10.7.

- Lines that are truncated come with a disclosure triangle
- A click on the triangle / a double click on the line / press on "Right Array" expand the NSCell and show the whole text

I was on the NSOutlineView way, but "Accessibility Inspector" reveals that it's not an outline view, but an NSCell.

An idea could be to catch the number of lines, and on specific events (click/double click/left array), modify the height of the current NSCell.

How can I add such a disclosure triangle in my cell ?
How can I catch such events ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console uses a view-based `NSTableView`. Each of the cells is a custom subclass of `NSTableCellView`, which enables it to include the disclosure button.

The disclosure button is probably just calling `noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:` on the table view, which in turn is calling `tableView:heightOfRow:` on the table view's delegate.

The implementation of the `tableView:heightOfRow:` delegate method would then be returning the larger height for the expanded rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I started to subclass NSTableCellView, but I can't succeed to show up to NSButton and my existing text which actually appears through bindings. Although it's not the question, can you advise me some sample codes on NSTableCellView subclassing ? I've looked at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475814/nsbutton-gets-drawn-inside-custom-nscell-but-is-not-actually-clickable) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280317/nsbuttoncell-inside-custom-nscell) but the code is not enough explicit for me ...