# NSButton in custom NSTextFieldCell

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton, nstextfieldcell

I just want to add a simple NSButton with setAction in a custom NStextFieldCell...
**But my processor takes over 100%...**

My code is as follows in my custom NStextFieldCell Class :

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
...
NSButton *myButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(cellFrame.origin.x+200, cellFrame.origin.y+5, 30, 30)];
[controlView addSubview: myButton];
[myButton setTitle: @"Button title!"];
[myButton setButtonType:NSMomentaryLightButton]; 
[myButton setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle]; 
[myButton setTarget:self];
[myButton setAction:@selector(myAction)];

...
}
```

Any Idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Your button should be declared outside of the method, otherwise it will be released, once the method has completed.

Comment: I try but don't work better

Comment: Same question：http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280317/nsbuttoncell-inside-custom-nscell