# How do I add custom cell in NSBrowser?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbrowser

I need to add a custom cell that will have a checkbox i.e. `NSButton` and an `NSImageCell`.

I searched and found I need to override `NSBrowserCell` to achieve this, but the delegate method doesn't return any `NSView` or `NSCell` as it does in `NSTableView`.

The delegate method reads like this:

```
- (void)browser:(NSBrowser *)sender
willDisplayCell:(NSImageCell *)cell
          atRow:(NSInteger)row
         column:(NSInteger)column{

    NSBrowserCell *bcell = [[NSBrowserCell alloc] initImageCell:nil];
    //    cell = bcell;

}
```

It is obvious that I can not return the cell, then how do I update the cell?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to replace all cells?

Comment: @Willeke:yes i want to replace all

Answer (score 1):

The cell class of a `NSBrowser` can be changed by setting

```
@property(strong) id cellPrototype;
```

> The prototype NSCell for displaying items in the matrices in the columns of the browser. The prototype NSCell instance is copied to display items in the matrices of the browser.

or with

```
- (void)setCellClass:(Class)factoryId;
```

> Sets the class of the cell to be used by the matrices in the columns of the browser. This method creates an instance of the class and sets cellPrototype.

Comment: How do I add NSButton? text & image are already there in NSBrowserCell.

Comment: See [NSButtonCell inside custom NSCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280317/nsbuttoncell-inside-custom-nscell).